# Apply + operator to subclassing array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I tried to concatenate two subclassing array.

But it returns a Array class not MyArray.

```
class MyArray < Array
end

foo = MyArray.new
bar = MyArray.new
p foo.class #=> MyArray
p (foo + bar).class #=> Array
```

How can I concatenate MyArray classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the method in your MyArray class and use `super`. You could also just alias_method :+, :concat

```
def concat(some_array)
  super
end

p foo.concat(bar).class #=> MyArray
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect! But I'm wondering why if I override + method directly, it doesn't work? like this. def +(some_array) super end

Comment: The best thing to do would be to go into ruby's source code and view how they do that exactly. It's probably something weird, but I can't think of it off the top of my head.

Comment: oh, it's too difficult for me to see ruby's source code. Though, thank you for your reply. :)